# A question on direct summand subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be an abelian group such that $G$ has no nontrivial direct summand subgroup. Is there a characterization of $G$?

Comment: If $G$ is finite, then $G$ is cyclic.

Comment: @ajotatxe or even if $G$ is finitely generated

Comment: The above is not a characterization though. cyclic of prime power oder is the exact criterion (in the finite case).

Comment: For infinite groups, any subgroup of $\Bbb Q$ is a torsion-free indecomposable abelian group, $\Bbb Q$ itself is a divisible such example, and the Prufer $p$-groups $\Bbb Z[1/p]/\Bbb Z$ are torsion examples (they are direct limits of cyclic groups $\Bbb Z/p^e\Bbb Z$). The $p$-adic integers $\Bbb Z_p$ under addition (the inverse limit of $\Bbb Z/p^e\Bbb Z$s) is also an example, since it's torsionfree while all its homomorphic images are torsion (namely, the $\Bbb Z/p^e\Bbb Z$s).

Comment: This is called "indecomposable", or "directly indecomposable to be more clear. An uncountable one is the group $\mathbf{Z}_p$ of $p$-adic integers for any prime $p$ (or any $\mathbf{Z}_{(p)}$-submodule therein, where $\mathbf{Z}_{(p)}=\mathbf{Z}_p\cap\mathbf{Q}$, the ring of rationals with denominator coprime to $p$). There is probably no nontrivial characterization, except in particular contexts (for f.g. abelian groups: cyclic groups of infinite or $p$-power order; for artinian abelian groups: cyclic and quasi-cyclic $p$-groups...).